# GNS3 nat configuration issue

Tags: cisco, routing, router, nat, gns3

I'm studying for my CCENT exam, and I'm trying to practice configuration of the NAT.

[image]

R1 configuration:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1211 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 200.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.2.2.3
!
!
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

R4 configuration:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 845 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R4
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 200.2.2.3 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 200.2.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.2.2.2
!
!
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

I didn't set up the NAT yet, but the PC3 is able to ping PC1 and PC2, can you explain me why? I thought that private IP won't be able to communicate with public without the NAT. What configuration should I create to be able to practice NAT?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherent in IP that defines public and private addressing. To IP, all IP addressing is valid, so your routers will happily route between what you believe is public and private addressing. The ISPs have agreed to not route the (arbitrarily) assigned private addresses on the public Internet. You can emulate that by placing ACLs on your routers (R4 if that is your "ISP" router) to block private addressing from being routed on your "public" network.

In any case, you can still set up NAT on R1 to practice using NAT, even if routing works between your "private" and "public" addressing. Simply configure your inside and outside interfaces, then configure your NAT.